# Ruby iterate through hash and compare value pairs

Tags: ruby, hash, iteration

My Ruby assignment is to iterate through a hash and return the key associated with the lowest value, *without* using any of the following methods:

```
#keys #values #min #sort #min_by
```

I don't understand how to iterate through the hash and store each pair as it comes through, compare it to the last pair that came through, and return the lowest key.  This is my code to show you my thought process, but it of course does not work.  Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks!

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
  index = 0 
  lowest_hash = {}

  name_hash.collect do |key, value|
    if value[index] < value[index + 1]
      lowest = value
      index = index + 1 
      key_for_min_value[value]

      return lowest
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: try `Hash#each`. 
`hash.each do |k,v| ...  end`

Comment: The *proper* solution is of course `hash.min_by(&:last).first`.

Comment: What's that? You want the keys for the 3 smallest values? With v2.2, no problem: `h.min_by(3,&:first).map(&:first)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is transforming our hash into an array;

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
  # Convert hash to array
  name_a = name_hash.to_a

  # Default key value
  d_value= 1000
  d_key= 0

  # Iterate new array 
  name_a.each do |i|
      # If current value is lower than default, change value&key 
      if i[1] < d_value
        d_value = i[1]
        d_key = i[0]
      end

   end

  return d_key

end
```

You might need to change d_value to something higher or find something more creative :)

Answer (score 5):

Track `min_value` and `key_for_min_value`. Iterate through the hash, and any time the current `value` is lower than `min_value`, update both of these vars. At the end of the loop, return `key_for_min_value`.

I didn't include sample code because, hey, this is homework. :) Good luck!

Comment: Karen, if a key-value pair of the hash is expressed `[k,v]`, with this approach you will be comparing `v` with `min_value`, and updating both `min_value` and `key_for_min_value` when `v < min_value`. But how do you get started? When you examine the first key-value pair, `min_value` has not been defined. There are two ways to handle that. The first is to initialize `min_value` to a very large number, the best choice being `Float:INFINITY`. The second way is initialize `min_value` to (say) `nil` and then write `if min_val == nil...else ...end`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Enumerable#reduce` method to compare entries and pick the smallest value. Each hash entry gets passed in as an array with 2 elements in reduce method, hence, I am using `Array#first` and `Array#last` methods to access key and values.

```
h = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 0}
p h.reduce{ |f, s| f.last > s.last ? s : f }.first
#=> "c"
```